# How do I write an argument function properly?

Tags: c, arrays, string, parameters, arguments

I have to C program called contains.c that takes two text strings as arguments and prints "true" followed by a newline if the second string is entirely contained within the first, or "false" followed by a newline otherwise.

For instance(in the command prompt)

```
$ ./contains 'I have a really bad feeling about this' 'bad feeling'
true

$ ./contains 'To be or not to be' 'That is the question'
false 

$ ./contains 'I am the walrus' 'I am the walrus'
true

$ ./contains 'the walrus' 'I am the walrus'
false

$ ./contains 'kmjnhbvc45&^$bn' '.'
false
```

Here is my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
int i;
int j;
int lenst1;
int lenst2;
int pos1;
int pos2;

if (lenst2>lenst1)
{
    printf("false");
    return 0;
}
for (j=0; j<lenst1;j++)
{
for (i=0; i<lenst2; i++)
{
    if (st2[i]==st1[j]) //NOT SURE HOW TO DEFINE "st2" and "st1"
    {
        pos1=j;
        pos2=i;
        while (pos2<lenst2)
        {
            pos2++;
            pos1++;
            if (st2[i]==st1[j])
            {

            }
            else
            {
                printf("false\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("true\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

I am not entirely sure how many flaws I have in my code but Xcode claimed that st2 and st1 needs to be defined.
It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me.

Comment: The number of elements/type needed for `st1[], st2[]` depends on `lenst1, lenst2` and prior code `if (lenst2>lenst1)` is bad as `lenst1, lenst2` are not yet assigned/initialized.  What is that `if()` trying to do?

Comment: These strings show up as undefined because you never actually defined the variables. Read up on the definition of a string in C. The type you are looking for is `char *`

Comment: And note that you can't just define any arbitrary function and run it. A C program requires at least a `main` function. Seems you need to go back and do a basic C tutorial or read a basic C book before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to read in your arguments.

```
char* st1 = argv[1];
char* st2 = argv[2];
lenst1 = strlen(st1);
lenst2 = strlen(st2);
```

Comment: This will fail if the arguments are not defined however. You will need to do some error checking to prevent segfaults

Answer (score 1):

You've had most of it right, but here are a few of the things you missed:

test the number of arguments:

```
if (argc != 3) {
    printf("wrong number of arguments provided\n");
    return -1;
}
```

capture your required variables:

```
int i, j, pos1, pos2;
char* st1 = argv[1];
char* st2 = argv[2];
int lenst1 = strlen(argv[1]);
int lenst2 = strlen(argv[2]);
```

Replace your if-else block with `if st2[i] != st1[j]`

Declare your main function to be named `main`

End your function with `return 0`;

Write `printf("false\n");` to pass your last test case. (do you see why?)

build `gcc contains.c -o contains`